# How to close just one of multiple windows of an application with tabs on mac with a shortcut?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, tabs

Many applications can have multiple tabs open on it, and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes a tab, not a window, a great and common example would be Chrome or any browser.

An example would be that I have two browser windows open with two tabs open on each.

The goal is to close just one window with a single shortcut.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes one tab. Holding it closes tabs repeatedly, but risky that will close tabs from the window we want to keep.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> closes all windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: -1 for not even making the effort to look in the menu bar.

Comment: Chrome or even any browser was mentioned as common example. There are many applications with tabs. However, I needed it for VSCode, and the answer I got works for it as well.

Comment: You get answers to the question you asked. If you ask the wrong question you may get the wrong answer. It's pretty much a Mac standard toolbox key command for any app which uses tabs, discoverable by the simple expedient of looking in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's [own Chrome documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en), you can close the current window on Mac using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.